# How do I print inpuits from .txt file with checking if the inputs are correct?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have .txt file with some info about people. I need to print this info with following formatting. I'm new to programming, so I don't really know how to properly use fscanf(). I also have to check if each item is correct. For example name can only be type char[40], number has to be integer divisible by 11, etc. If the input is incorrect, program will print message: "Incorrect input: number\n". Can you help me with this?
File:

```
James Novak
6608133268
D99
20190204

Mary Novak
0256157704
B24
20190112
```

Expected output:

```
Name: James Novak
Number: 9206110980
Diagnosis: D99
Date: 20190204

Name: Mary Novak
Number: 7256235756
Diagnosis: B24
Date: 20190112
```

So far I only managed to print the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char s[50];


    f=fopen("patients.txt","r");
    if (!f)
        return 1;
    while (fgets(s,50,f)!=NULL) 
    
    printf("%s",s); 
       
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I was thinking about using loop for checking the inputs, but I have no idea how to do that yet.

Comment: Did you write code to read the file and display its content, line by line, without the expected formatting?

Comment: `fscanf()` is not good at dealing with malformed input. You should read input via `fgets()` and parse it by yourself. After checking input format is correct, `sscanf()` may be useful to convert strings to integers.

Comment: Please show what you have tried; evidence of effort is expected, rather than expecting SO to just write code for you.

Comment: "How do I print using fscanf from .txt file with checking if the input is correct?" Not. You read whole lines and parse them explicitly for correctness. `scanf()` and family are for correct input. See http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a good question from a new programmer. But, the answers unfortunately open up a vast can of worms. You know all that trouble Microsoft has with  needing  to  issue security  patches?  A good fraction of it is because a lot of their legacy system code uses C language text string processing, where buffer overruns are easy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input file comes in chunks of four lines each: name, number, diagnosis, date.

Can you rely on that?  If so, you don't need to use `fscanf()`. Each input item will come from it's own line of your file, so you can read the lines one by one with `fgets()`. It's less tetchy to use than `fscanf()`.  (This isn't debugged.)

```
int bufferLength = 1024; /* defend against unexpectedly long lines */
char buffer [bufferLength + 1];
int number = 0;
/* open the file */
FILE* filePointer;
filePointer = fopen("file.txt", "r");

while (1) {  /* repeat until break */
    if (!fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) break;
    /* Remove any trailing newline-type characters */
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
    if (strlen(buffer) > 40) printf("Name too long.\n");
    printf ("Name: %s\n", buffer);   

    if (!fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) break;
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
    number = atoi(buffer);
    if (number == 0) printf("bad number: %s", buffer);
    printf ("Number: %s\n", buffer);   

    if (!fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) break;
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
    printf ("Diagnosis: %s\n", buffer);   

    if (!fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) break;
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
    printf ("Date: %s\n", buffer);   
}
fclose(filePointer);
```

I could have put the repetitive code into a function, but I'll leave that to you.

And, with  respect, "C" is **not the best choice of language** for this sort of work. Its text-string handling is (a) difficult and (b) unsafe, that is, far too easy for cybercreeps to attack. Personally, I would never use C to handle other peoples' health care data.

Python might be a better choice of language for you.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. Unfortunately, I have to use C language, because I'm in high school which requires us to use only C language. As for the health care data, I chose this only for example, so nothing bad will happen :)

Comment: Oh, OK. I get it. This old guy had to use C a long time ago  because it was that or FORTRAN.  Still, C text-string processing is nasty and vulnerable. I've burned myself many times.  Try it for yourself .... put a line of text with 2000 characters into your file and see what happens. (Hold down a key on your keyboard.)